# String to int conversion using toInt function

Tags: elm

I am trying to convert a string  to integer using String.toInt. However, when I want to bind the result to a variable and then do some simple math with it I get this error:

> Function `add` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
>
> ```
> Int
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> Result String Int
> ```

How can I just extract the integer part of the result?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

toInt can fail in parsing. You need to check it using a case statement:

```
case toInt str of
  Err msg -> ... -- do something with the error message
  Ok val -> ... -- val is an Int which you can add
```

[More about Result here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/Result)

Comment: For Elm 0.19 `toInt` returns `Maybe Int` instead of a `Result`, so this answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 36):

Here's how to supply the conversion with a default value in case the parsing fails.

```
String.toInt "5" |> Result.toMaybe |> Maybe.withDefault 0
```

Comment: Has this behaviour been changed? for me this code worked instead 'String.toInt newContent |> Maybe.withDefault 0'. I am using elm-version 0.19.0 and I don't understand why I get a Maybe back instead of a result

Answer (score 11):

The integer can also be pulled out using

```
Result.withDefault 0 (String.toInt "2")
```

You can read more about it [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/String#toInt)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Elm String reference documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/String#toInt), if you are extracting a number from some raw user input, you will typically want to use `Result.withDefault` to handle bad data in case parsing fails. You can chain this operation using pipes for cleaner code:

```
String.toInt "5" |> Result.withDefault 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Maybe.withDefault 0 (String.toInt "42")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map:

```
answer = Result.map2 (+) (String.toInt "1") (String.toInt "2")
```

[map2](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Result#map2):

> Apply a function to two results, if both results are Ok. If not, the
>   first argument which is an Err will propagate through.

to have the `add` result as a string

```
resultAsString r =
    case r of
        Err msg -> msg
        Ok value -> toString value

resultAsString answer
```

to make things easier you can create an `addStrings` function:

```
addStrings : String -> String -> Result String Int
addStrings a b =
    Result.map2 (+) (String.toInt a) (String.toInt b)
```

You can even get away with the `Result` type altogether:

```
addStrings : String -> String -> String
addStrings a b =
    let
        r =
            Result.map2 (+) (String.toInt a) (String.toInt b)
    in
    case r of
        Err msg ->
            msg

        Ok value ->
            toString value
```

Testing

```
import Html exposing (Html, text)

main : Html msg
main =
    text (addStrings "1" "2")


output 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `withDefault` method forces you to define a value that can be used for calculations but it is not always possible to establish a value that is significant for errors. Most often you need all the possible values, and default is not fit. Here I provide a result type check function you can use to decide if you use or not the converted value:

```
isErrorResult r =
    case r of
        Err msg ->
            True

        Ok value ->
            False
```

You can use it like this:

```
r = String.toInt "20b"

if isErrorResult r then
    -- not a valid Interger, abort or whatever
else
    -- a good integer, extract it
    a = Result.withDefault 0 r
    -- and make good use of it
```

the `default` value (0 in this case) passed to `withDefault` is meaningless, because we made sure that `r` is not an `Err`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below.

```
---- Elm 0.19.0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
Read <https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/repl> to learn more: exit, help, imports, etc.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> parseInt string = String.toInt string
<function> : String -> Maybe Int
> resultParseInt string = \
|   Result.fromMaybe ("error parsing string: " ++ string) (parseInt string)
<function> : String -> Result String Int
> resultParseInt "12"
Ok 12 : Result String Int
> resultParseInt "12ll"
Err ("error parsing string: 12ll") : Result String Int
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed guys answers a bit, since it appears to be of type Maybe

```
isErrorResult : String -> Bool
isErrorResult r =
case String.toInt r of
    Nothing -> True
    Just value -> False
```